# How to align indent space between two words in drop-down list?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have created drop-down list with two different text in which I need tab space, I have used word-spacing but this didn't work for me.

Expected output:

```
Volvo            2
Saab             4
Opel             6
```

As shown above those two values should come with maximum space between them while displaying in drop-down list.

```css
#quantity_margin {
  word-spacing: 5.2em;
}
```

```html
<select id="quantity_margin">
 <option value="">option   quantity</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo  2</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab    4</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel    6</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi    7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this without creating your own list options and use much more CSS and maybe some javascript. But, if you put the quantity first, the options will be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I just used `&emsp;`. 1 `&emsp;` is equal to about 4 `&nbsp` (spaces) Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#quantity_margin {
  word-spacing: 5.2em;
}
</style>
<body>
<select id="quantity_margin">
 <option value="">option   quantity</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;2</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;4</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;6</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;7</option>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```